# How do I make the webcam work with flash 10.2.161.23?

Tags: 10.10, flash, 64-bit, webcam

I have a webcam and it works with cheese and gmail video. The problem is that it doesn't work on a lot of broadcasting websites (like tinychat). The flash permission popup doesn't appear when I try to use the webcam.

ubuntu 10.10 (x64) with flash 10.2.161.23 (x64).

Are there extra steps to be done?

Comment: Do you use the 32-bit or the 64-bit flash plugin?

Comment: 64-bit flash plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works here for example: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
It's not working on tinychat so maybe it's a but on tiny's side.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but not on tinychat but on the exact URL you posted in your reply above. I get the permissions dialog but clicking it does absolutely nothing. I've tried in both Chrome and FF on Ubuntu and Chrome and FF on Windows XP (in VirtualBox) - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the settings on this page?

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html

Comment: Yes I put the url in the safe list. Still doesn't work. The websites still thinks that it does not have access to the cam and asks me to try again.